# Mersenne Twister's vulnerabilty with small-size distributions

Tags: cryptanalysis, random-number-generator, pseudo-random-generator, security-definition

C++ rookie here, trying to wrap his head around (CS)PRNGs.

I (assume that I) already understand the concept of the Mersenne Twister being "broken" (i.e. not cryptographically secure) due to its linear recurrence; so an attacker may figure out its internal state by knowing a sufficient amount of outputs and could then predict future outputs.

**My question**: Does this also apply to MT engines whose output values are distributed over a very small range? Like

```
std::mt19937 mt_rand(/* assuming secure seeding here */);
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0,127);
uint8_t rand7bit = dist(mr_rand);
```

, where the 32 bit output of the std::mt19937 template is effectively "reduced" to 7bit of actual information?

Would an attacker still be able to break this, even if he/she could ONLY access the distributed 7-bit values? (which are -theoretically- lacking 25 bits of the "full size" information?)

Or am I getting something wrong here?

Comment: My guess is that it would simply take a larger number of samples. It's an entirely linear RNG. Every bit of output can be related to every bit of its initial internal state with a system of linear equations. You'd need at least as many bits of output (equations) as there are bits of input (variables) to recover (solve for) the state.

Comment: Also, if you’re throwing away 25 out of 32 bits of state you’re slowing MT down. Just use a real CSPRNG (such as the very fast ChaCha20) instead. Why do you even  _want_ to use MT in a security-related setting? MT isn’t very good or fast even when compared to other state-of-the-art statistical (insecure) RNGs.